# JMeter JMS Point-to-Point Sampler with values of JNDI Properties as variables

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to create JNDI Properties values as variables from a config file but when I use the command:

```
${__groovy(vars.getObject("myTrustedCerts"))}
```

as the value, the error is:

```
2021-06-25 14:49:08,682 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JMSSampler: Not permitted: empty file name
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Not permitted: empty file name"
```

But the variable `myTrustedCerts` is correctly filled:

```
2021-06-25 14:49:08,732 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: JSR223 The value of myTrustedCerts = C:/GEMS5.0/Gems/figeastrustchain.cer.pem
```

The variable is filled from an xml file:

```
vars.putObject("myTrustedCerts",xml.ssl_trusted_certs).toString()
```

It works when I fill the value with the full path, but I want it to be generic from a config file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) before your JMS Point-to-Point sampler and look into [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to ensure that the variable is there and it has ancitipated value

I think you have an error/typo in this line:

```
vars.putObject("myTrustedCerts",xml.ssl_trusted_certs).toString()
```

I believe it should look like:

```
vars.putObject("myTrustedCerts", xml.ssl_trusted_certs.toString())
```

If you look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) you should see some Groovy-syntax-related errors, once you fix them you should get expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I changed the line to set up my variable as you explained and I added a Debug Sampler. The variables are correct, but it still doesn't work. Same error message. It seems that the JMS Point-to-Point is executed before my JSR223 Sampler where my variables are initialized. Anything I can do about order of execution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a alternative way to resolve my issue: I use properties instead of variables. To be sure it's done in the right order, I use multiple threads: in the first one, I initialize the properties and in the next one I use them